# CakePHP 3.0 - Association 'propertyName' not being applied to query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

After setting the associations, I will run a paginate with the proper containable and I will get the results I intended. However, I'd like to name the data to distinguish it from associations already made between tables.

I use the `propertyName` for such a task, but when I do, the result is that the property is always null, and the containable I asked for will show up under the table name.

For example:

```
// MarksTable.php    
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('marks');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->belongsTo('Hunts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'hunt_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Winners', [
        'className' => 'Pictures',
        'foreignKey' => 'winner_id',
        'propertyName' => 'banana'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Submissions', [
        'className' => 'Pictures',
        'foreignKey' => 'mark_id',
        'propertyName' => 'submissions'
    ]);
}
```

And the controller:

```
// AdminController.php

public function marks() {

    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Hunts.Games', 'Submissions.Users', 'Winners'],
        'order' => ['Marks.id' => 'DESC']
    ];

    $this->set('marks', $this->paginate('Marks'));
}
```

The variables I get:

[image: variable dump]

Any suggestions on how to 'rename' the association? I've tried the reciprocal with the same result (ie: `Pictures hasOne Winners`), and the property was named `Mark` instead of `banana`, but the data was correct.

EDIT: Table structure --

```
marks       Type        Null    Default
id          int(11)     No       
name        varchar(45) No       
hunt_id     int(11)     No       
winner_id   int(11)     Yes     NULL     


pictures    Type            Null    
id          int(11)         No       
user_id     int(11)         No       
mark_id     int(11)         No       
guid        varchar(255)    No       
timestamp   datetime        No
```

The idea is that, once the pictures have been voted on, a mark (think 'prompt') will be updated with the winning pictures.id. It'd save some SQL time if we only needed to grab which marks have been won, and we can use associations to find the relevant picture (and picture.user) if need-be. I'll be the first to admit it's not a good place for the column, though.

Comment: The association should definitly be `hasOne` with your current schema. For a `belongsTo` the `winner_id` column would need to be in the `pictures` table. The property name not being used seems really weird, however from looking at your dump, it seems that the property name actually _is_ used, but it _additionally_ adds a property that uses the name of the association? Are you using a recent stable release? Have you tried it with a fresh CakePHP installation? Have you tried to reduce the containments to figure whether there's a conflict? What does your DB schema look like exactly?

Comment: I've updated the post to show DB structure of the two tables. As for the hasOne vs belongsTo -- Using hasOne will cause cake to look for Pictures.winner_id. Using the proper foreign key for that type of association (mark_id) won't let me 'attach' it to the winner_id, only Mark.id . Is there some conditional wizardry I could use to make this association?
As for test conditions, I'm on 3.0 (which is stable, right!?), I haven't tried on a new installation (because I'm clearly doing something wrong, and because propertyName works with other associations). And yes, I've removed other containables.

Comment: Does the problem only happen with hasOne associations? If that is the case please open a ticket in the cakephp issue tracker so this can be fixed.

Comment: It happens with the belongsTo association I created. Strangely, naming the association after the table ('Pictures'), and removing the className parameter 'resolved' the issue and allowed the data to be named with the propertyName parameter. Of course, that means I have to use 'Pictures' whenever I contain winners, and 'Submissions' when I want to contain all pictures. I don't like it, but I can work with it, now.